# Implementing a 1D Convolution SIMD Friendly in Julia

Tags: performance, julia, simd

I want to implement a 1D convolution in Julia using the direct calculation since the [`conv()`](https://docs.juliadsp.org/stable/convolutions/#DSP.conv) function in [DSP.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDSP/DSP.jl) uses DFT (`fft`) based methods.

In order to make it fast, I'd like the code to be SIMD friendly (I am OK with using [LoopVectorization.jl](https://github.com/JuliaSIMD/LoopVectorization.jl)).

The trivial code is:

```
using BenchmarkTools;

function _Conv1D!( vO :: Array{T, 1}, vA :: Array{T, 1}, vB :: Array{T, 1} ) :: Array{T, 1} where {T <: Real}

    lenA = length(vA);
    lenB = length(vB);

    fill!(vO, zero(T));
    for idxB in 1:lenB
        @simd for idxA in 1:lenA
            @inbounds vO[idxA + idxB - 1] += vA[idxA] * vB[idxB];
        end
    end

    return vO;

end

function _Conv1D( vA :: Array{T, 1}, vB :: Array{T, 1} ) :: Array{T, 1} where {T <: Real}

    lenA = length(vA);
    lenB = length(vB);

    vO = Array{T, 1}(undef, lenA + lenB - 1);

    return _Conv1D!(vO, vA, vB);

end

numSamplesA = 1000;
numSamplesB = 15;

vA = rand(numSamplesA);
vB = rand(numSamplesB);
vO = rand(numSamplesA + numSamplesB - 1);

@benchmark _Conv1D($vA, $vB)
```

I get:

```
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 9 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  2.522 μs … 558.844 μs  ┊ GC (min … max):  0.00% … 99.28%
 Time  (median):     3.333 μs               ┊ GC (median):     0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   4.321 μs ±  13.718 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  10.38% ±  3.67%

     ██▆        ▂    
  ▃▄▃███▆▅▇▆▄▂▃▇██▄▂▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▂▂▃▃▃▃▂▂▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁ ▂
  2.52 μs         Histogram: frequency by time        8.51 μs <

 Memory estimate: 8.06 KiB, allocs estimate: 1.
```

I read Chris Elrod's post [Orthogonalize Indices](https://spmd.org/posts/orthogonalizing_loops/).
Basically I tried removing the inner loop and got something like:

```
function Conv1D!( vO :: Array{T, 1}, vA :: Array{T, 1}, vB :: Array{T, 1} ) :: Array{T, 1} where {T <: Real}

    lenA = length(vA);
    lenB = length(vB);
    lenO = length(vO);
    vC   = view(vB, lenB:-1:1);
    @simd for ii in 1:lenO
        # Rolling vB over vA
        startIdxA = max(1, ii - lenB + 1);
        endIdxA   = min(lenA, ii);
        startIdxC = max(lenB - ii + 1, 1);
        endIdxC   = min(lenB, lenO - ii + 1);
        # println("startA = $startIdxA, endA = $endIdxA, startC = $startIdxC, endC = $endIdxC");
        @inbounds vO[ii] = sum(view(vA, startIdxA:endIdxA) .* view(vC, startIdxC:endIdxC));
    end

    return vO;

end

function Conv1D( vA :: Array{T, 1}, vB :: Array{T, 1} ) :: Array{T, 1} where {T <: Real}

    lenA = length(vA);
    lenB = length(vB);

    vO = Array{T, 1}(undef, lenA + lenB - 1);

    return Conv1D!(vO, vA, vB);

end

numSamplesA = 1000;
numSamplesB = 15;

vA = rand(numSamplesA);
vB = rand(numSamplesB);
vO = rand(numSamplesA + numSamplesB - 1);

@benchmark Conv1D($vA, $vB)
```

Yet I get much much slower results.

Is there anything I can do to improve results any farther?
Maybe something to make the code much more SIMD friendly?

A Godbold link for `_Conv1D!()`: https://godbolt.org/z/e8W7e473h.

**Remark**: Originally, in `Conv1D!()`, I used `@inbounds vO[ii] = dot(view(vA, startIdxA:endIdxA), view(vC, startIdxC:endIdxC));`. It was slower.

Comment: You didn't include a https://godbolt.org link. Can you describe how the generated code for v2 differs from the (faster) v1 code?

Comment: @J_H, I wish I knew how to analyze the lower level code :-). I guess than I'd be able to do the next step and improve it.

Comment: I was suggesting that if you offer godbolt links to the generated code, you'll make it easier for a diverse audience of contributors to compare them and to comment on them. If you accompany that with remarks on any insights you've gleaned, so much the better.

Comment: I see your point. Embraced it: https://godbolt.org/z/e8W7e473h. This is the link.

Comment: You have only provided the godbolt link for one of your test cases, likewise for your benchmarks. Running your second benchmark with benchmarking makes it obvious why:
A: `195.214 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)` B: `1.700 ms (1999 allocations: 7.90 MiB)` You're generating a load of temporary arrays.

Comment: @DeathIncarnate, But why? Everything is a view.

Comment: `view(vA, startIdxA:endIdxA) .* view(vC, startIdxC:endIdxC)` won't be a view

Comment: I see. Could you suggest (As an answer, so I'll be able to +1 to the least) a way to do it without allocations? I guess by some kind of comprehension?

Comment: In short, not really. My Julia isn't really good enough as I have only really played with it briefly, hence why it's all been comments.

Comment: Originally I had `dot()` but I thought a direct simple code would be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on code by [Chris Elrod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8183881) I managed to come to this:

```
function Conv1D!( vO :: Vector{T}, vA :: Vector{T}, vB :: Vector{T} ) where {T <: Real}

    J = length(vA);
    K = length(vB); #<! Assumed to be the Kernel
    
    # Optimized for the case the kernel is in vB (Shorter)
    J < K && return Conv1D!(vO, vB, vA);
    
    I = J + K - 1; #<! Output length
    
    @turbo for ii in 1:(K - 1) #<! Head
        sumVal = zero(T);
        for kk in 1:K
            ib0 = (ii >= kk);
            oa = ib0 ? vA[ii - kk + 1] : zero(T);
            sumVal += vB[kk] * oa;
        end
        vO[ii] = sumVal;
    end
    @turbo inline=true for ii in K:(J - 1) #<! Middle
        sumVal = zero(T);
        for kk in 1:K
            sumVal += vB[kk] * vA[ii - kk + 1];
        end
        vO[ii] = sumVal;
    end
    @turbo for ii in J:I #<! Tail
        sumVal = zero(T);
        for kk in 1:K
            ib0 = (ii < J + kk);
            oa = ib0 ? vA[ii - kk + 1] : zero(T);
            sumVal += vB[kk] * oa;
        end
        vO[ii] = sumVal;
    end
    return vO
end
```

This code will efficiently use the SIMD capabilities of the CPU (Assuming `x64` CPU).

The main idea is to replace the series of `if` with 3 optimized cases for beginning of the signal, middle and the end.
This makes the code *SIMD* friendly.

Pay attention that it won't work well with `@simd` instead of `@turbo`.

Comment: Thanks for posting this code.  It's a good idea to summarise which changes you made, and why - a self-answer ought to review the code, just like any other answer.

Comment: @TobySpeight, I added the explicit information.